# Include appendix figures/tables in Lof/Lot, but with some space from the last chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I have one question about spacing in the List of Figures/Tables. My thesis has some figures and tables in the appendix; when I set the follwing code to let them be visible in the Lot/Lof, there is no spacing between, for example, the first figure of the Appendix and the last one of a chapter. But, this spacing is present when figures come from different chapters. Here is a MWE to have an idea of what I'm saying. I don't know whether it is feasible or not, I'm not that good at Latex. If anyone has any tips, please let me know, thanks!

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, openright, cleardoublepage=empty]{book}
\usepackage[font=small,format=hang,labelfont={sf,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents\listoftables\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\section{one}
\section{two}
\section{three}
One image
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-c}
    \caption[Capital letter C]{This is capital letter C}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
and a table:
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2   \\ 
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption[1 and 2 data table]{This is a table with 1 and 2}
\label{Table}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Second}
Another image
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-golden}
    \caption[Golden]{This is golden image}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter*{Appendix}
\renewcommand\thefigure{A.\arabic{figure}}  
\setcounter{figure}{0} 

\renewcommand\thetable{T.\arabic{table}}  
\setcounter{table}{0} 

Another image
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b}
    \caption[Capital letter B]{This is capital letter B}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

and another table:
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
3 & 4   \\ 
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption[3 and 4 data table]{This is a table with 3 and 4}
\label{Table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to add `\appendix` before the chapter Appendix, and to number the chapter. After that, the `\titleformat` command from the `titlesec` package can be used to format the Appendix chapter title so it will appear as if it was unnumbered.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside, openright, cleardoublepage=empty]{book}
\usepackage[font=small,format=hang,labelfont={sf,bf}]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents\listoftables\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\section{one}
\section{two}
\section{three}
One image
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-c}
    \caption[Capital letter C]{This is capital letter C}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
and a table:
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1 & 2   \\ 
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption[1 and 2 data table]{This is a table with 1 and 2}
\label{Table}
\end{table}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Second}
Another image
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-golden}
    \caption[Golden]{This is golden image}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{}{-\baselineskip}{\Huge}
\chapter{Appendix}
\renewcommand\thetable{T.\arabic{table}}

Another image
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b}
    \caption[Capital letter B]{This is capital letter B}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

and another table:
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
3 & 4   \\ 
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption[3 and 4 data table]{This is a table with 3 and 4}
\label{Table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Vincent, I think I'll use this tip. Many thanks!